# How to test if A is not equal to B or C in Bash Script conditional expression

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, centos

I want the user to be forced into entering the correct variable in order to complete the script.

```
var_hadoop="y"

read -p "Install Hadoop after reboot? [y/n]: " var_hadoop

while  ! [ $var_hadoop = "y" ] || ! [ $var_hadoop = "n" ]; do
        echo "Only enter either \"y\" or \"n\"."
        read -p "Install Hadoop after reboot? [y/n]: " var_hadoop
done
```

I have tried a number of different layouts and searched around but have not found anything for:

```
!((A == B) or (A == C))
```

or

```
((A <> B) and (A <> C))
```

Comment: `[ $var_hadoop = "y" ]` is somewhat silly -- it leaves unquoted the thing that needs to be quoted (the variable expansion) and quotes the thing where it doesn't matter (the string literal `y`).

Comment: re: `! [ $var_hadoop = "y" ] || ! [ $var_hadoop = "n" ]`, by the way, it would behave the same buggy way in *any* language, since even when `var_hadoop=y`, it'll be not-equal to `n`, and when it's `n` it'll be not-equal to `y`, so you'll always have at least one branch false (or, after the negation, true). Use something that's neither `y` or `n` and you have **both** branches false (or, post-negation, true), but that sends your flow control down the exact same path.

Comment: Other SO longbeards: Don't we have a generic question for the misunderstanding of precedence and boolean logic here?

Comment: (Back on the topic of quoting, by the way -- http://shellcheck.net/ does good automated analysis on that point; I strongly suggest using it. You can download and compile the source to be run locally, if you don't want to be sending content offsite).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conventional, idiomatic, POSIX-compliant approach is to use a `case` statement:

```
case $var_hadoop in
   y) : handle "y" here ;;
   n) : handle "n" here ;;
   *) echo 'Either enter "y" or "n"' ;;
esac
```

That said, the following works in bash or other shells with ksh extensions to POSIX:

```
if ! [[ $var_hadoop = [yn] ]]; then
  echo 'Either enter "y" or "n"'
fi
```

...and the following works in all POSIX shells:

```
if ! { [ "$var_hadoop" = y ] || [ "$var_hadoop" = n ]; }; then
  echo 'Either enter "y" or "n"'
fi
```

Comment: Great answer, however testing the the second answer first  I get: shell.sh: 4: shell.sh: [[: not found

Comment: @AirCombat, then your shell isn't really bash. If you want answers that work with `#!/bin/sh`, not `#!/bin/bash` (or `sh yourscript` as opposed to `bash yourscript`), you need to tag your question appropriately.

Comment: I have been using sh instead of bash incorrectly for an embarrasing amount of time it turns out ( stating bash at the top but using sh)

Comment: It confuses matters further that `/bin/sh` is *sometimes* implemented by bash (depending on your OS or distribution)... but even when it is, it tends to be bash running in POSIX compatibility mode, so it doesn't have all its extensions enabled.

Answer (score 1):

In a POSIX compliant manner, you can also make use of the `expr string : regex` test to enforce a `y/n` answer:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "Install Hadoop after reboot? [y/n]: "
read var_hadoop

while [ $(expr "x$var_hadoop" : "x[yn]") -eq 0 ]; do
    printf "Only enter either \"y\" or \"n\".\n"
    printf "Install Hadoop after reboot? [y/n]: "
    read var_hadoop
done
```

Comment: Needs more quotes. What if you have a file named `xy` or `xn` is your current directory when running this? The regex will never make it to `expr` because it's expandable as a glob.